# Symfony installation issue

Tags: php, symfony, installation

I am new in `Symfony`. I tried to install a Symfony in my localhost as per instruction of this [page](http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_big_picture.html) .

I tried to execute this command 
`php -r "readfile('http://symfony.com/installer');" > symfony.phar`

I got this warning

```
(PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'D:\php\php\ext\intl.so' - The specified module could not found.)
```

Why am I getting this warning?? Could anyone help me in this regard ??

Thanks

Comment: What's your OS/php/apache...?

Comment: Thanks @smarber for your reply.

My OS - Windows 8 

My PHP - 5.5.6

My Apache - 2.4.7


Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is relative to this : https://www.php.net/manual/en/intl.installation.php